# use different namespace based on language

Tags: serialization, namespaces, deserialization, schema, flatbuffers

The flatbuffer schema file has `namespace` directive, which defines the namespace in the generated code. But the problem is that the style of namespace is language dependent, for example, in `msg.fbs`:

```
namespace Mycompany.myorg.app;
```

If I generate C++ code, the namespace will be:

```
namespace Mycompany {
  namespace myorg {
    namespace app {
} } }
```

This is right, but if I generate java code, it will be in the same structure:

```
package Mycompany.myorg.app;
```

But in java it should be sth like `com.mycompany.myorg.app`. Is it to have a dynamic namespace configuration based on the language?

Comment: I don't think that currently exists, but i would be supportive of adding that with a PR.